# GARCH Optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, arima

I'm trying to fit a GARCH(1,1) model using rugarch library in R to predict S&P500 returns for the next 25 days. I have hard coded the ARIMA p and q to be 4 and 4 respectively for this example. However, each time I run this, it comes up as an optimization error.

Here is the code:

```
getSymbols("^GSPC", from="2016-01-01")
asset = diff(log(Cl(GSPC)))
returns = as.numeric(asset)

spec = ugarchspec(
    variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)),
    mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(
      4,4                                   
      ), include.mean=T),
    distribution.model="sged"
    )

fit = ugarchfit(
  spec, returns, solver = 'hybrid')
```

and here is the error:

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = 
TRUE,  : 
 initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

Comment: Get rid of any NA's in your data.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen, it works now!